# Is there a way to turn off thw windows 10 fan

Tags: windows-10

My fan run when Microsoft Edge is the only thisng open and it really annoying. Is there any way to turn it off? IS really loud and annoying. is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This is not a Windows 10 issue, its likely a cpu utilisation issue.  You may want to advise what motherboard or laptop or PC model you have.

Comment: Your fan is likely running at low speed when Edge is not running. (1) do not turn the fan off ALWAYS a bad thing to do (2) Look for Edge extensions. Edge does not cause my fan to run on high.